# File Explorer doesn`t show files but os.listdir() does

Tags: python, excel, pandas, directory

I created few folders and files in python with os.mkdir(), pd.to_excel, xlsxwriter successfully (with no errors) and i can open the files and see them in os.listdir().
But i cannot see any of them in Windows. Search in Folder Explorer failed. Even created in current directory files don`t appear in the folder. Why??

The code works correctly on another machine.
Huge thank you in advance

Comment: Why do you use xlsxwriter? Did you close the file?

Comment: Explorer must be hiding them for some reason. What are the filenames?

Comment: A minimal working example would help here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.